# How to delete heading remaining spaces after deleting many fields?

Tags: awk, tar

(sorry but i will write "I" as "i" because "I" is always confused with pipe character;)

i have a tar file, so i can see a list by the "-t" option. each line will be like below.

```
-rwxr-x--- admin/users  287110 2017-04-01 12:49 017_0401/345 alice.wav
```

we can see that path is "017_0401/" and filename is "345 alice.wav" which has space.

and what i need is just filename and size info.

for "awk", $3 is size, $6 and rest part will be a filename.

unfortunately, many of the files have unpredictable numbers of spaces in their names (not named by me).

i want "awk" to make this list to be like below. ("filename"\t"size")

```
017_0401/345 alice.wav [tab] 287110
```

so, i tried "awk" like this:

```sh
   cat tarlist.txt | awk '{zsize=$3; $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; print $0"\t"zsize;}'
   #rem: i had to use $0 because many files have spaces in the name.
```

but the result would have heading spaces like below.

```
[5spaces]017_0401/345 alice.wav [tab] 287110
```

what i need is like...

```
017_0401/345 alice.wav [tab] 287110
```

what can i do to eliminate remainder spaces from 5 deleted fields?
thanks for reading till here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all leading spaces from `$0` with GNU awk:

```
tar ... | awk '{size=$3; $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; gsub(/^ */, ""); print $0 "\t" size}'
```

Comment: That would change tabs and/or multiple contiguous blanks in each file name to a single blank char and the OP specifically warned us that `unfortunately, many of the files have unpredictable numbers of spaces in their names` so YMMV!

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you, I hadn't considered that. I recommend to add `-F ' {1}'` in this case.

Comment: that'd still change a file named `foo<blank><blank>bar` to `foo<blank>bar`. There's just no robust way to do this with assigning to fields.

Comment: @EdMorton: thank you but as i know, caret('`^`') means the beginning of line. so main answer by @Cysus feels quite wright, cuz it will delete only beginning spaces, not working on filenames. am i right? or am i fool?

Comment: I wouldn't say you're a fool but you're not right. `^` means beginning of string, not beginning of line, but that's irrelevant here as it's assigning anything to a field (e.g. `$5=""`) that causes awk to replace all chains of contiguous white space with single blank chars as described in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is the kind of simple substitution on individual lines is what sed was created to do. With GNU sed for `-E` and `\s/\S`:

```
$ echo '-rwxr-x--- admin/users  287110 2017-04-01 12:49 017_0401/345 alice.wav' |
    sed -E 's/^(\S*\s*){2}(\S*)\s*(\S*\s*){2}(.*)/\4\t\2/'
017_0401/345 alice.wav  287110
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ echo '-rwxr-x--- admin/users  287110 2017-04-01 12:49 017_0401/345 alice.wav' |
    sed 's/^\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\)\{2\}\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*\)\{2\}\(.*\)/\4\t\2/'
017_0401/345 alice.wav  287110
```

If you prefer awk though, with GNU awk for `\s/\S`:

```
$ echo '-rwxr-x--- admin/users  287110 2017-04-01 12:49 017_0401/345 alice.wav' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{size=$3; sub(/^(\S+\s+){5}/,""); print $0, size}'
017_0401/345 alice.wav  287110
```

or with any POSIX awk:

```
$ echo '-rwxr-x--- admin/users  287110 2017-04-01 12:49 017_0401/345 alice.wav' |
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{size=$3; sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){5}/,""); print $0, size}'
017_0401/345 alice.wav  287110
```

The above will work as long as your file names can't contain newlines.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different take... remove everything up to the colon (`:`) and the three characters after it:

```
tar tvf ... | gawk '{print gensub(/[^:]*:...(.*)/,"\\1\t"$3,1)}'
```

This will still work even if the file/directory name starts with a space. For those new to `awk`, that says...

*"Capture everything following a colon and the three following characters as capture group 1. Print capture group 1 followed by a tab and field 3. Only do this for the first occurrence of a colon."*

Note that **GNU** `awk` is required for `gensub()`. See Ed Morton's comment.

---

If you **really** want to *"code golf"* it and make it shorter, more arcane and unintelligible, you can use:

```
tar ... | gawk '{$0=gensub(/.*:...(.*)/,"\\1\t"$3,1)}1'
```

Comment: dare shall i put on another question on your oracle? :)
i can't complete the regex for "thousands separator" in linux df command.
https://superuser.com/questions/1494657/thousands-separator-in-linux-df-command/